# html validation error on stackoverflow.com frontpage

Tags: bug, status-completed, homepage, validation

on the frontpage(other pages i checked works fine) of stackoverflow.com there is a feed link which generates id with unnecessary  string " test"

```
<div id="feed-link">
    <div id="feed-link-text test"><a href="/feeds" title="the 30 most recent questions"><span class="feed-icon"></span>recent questions feed</a></div>
</div>
```

**`id="feed-link-text test"`** why the **`"test"`** is given? shouldn't it be **`id="feed-link-text"`** or does it have any use?

Comment: heheh, it is to break regex `/id="[\w-]+"/` screen scraping. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fixed in code, and deployed everywhere except SO. It's main use is to cause embarrassment and beatings to the *idiot* who committed code with that in